# Apppic hide/disable from galary and file manager but it must showing in my application

Tags: android, image

I have an application which take picture and save it in folder in sd card, after I upload it to server, my requirement is my pic taken from the application should not get displayed in device gallery as well as file manager (except some HD app) but after hiding the folder / images it must shown in my application.

I have used some solutions like adding "." before any folder name, but using this will disappear my pic from my application too so it is useless,

I also used .nomedia file concept but it is not working properly, images show in file manager.

Any help will be appreciated...

Answer (score 0):

Indeed a .nomedia file in a folder will not show pictures from that folder in Gallery app. But you can never prevent a file explorer to display them. `add "." before folder name it will dispear pic my application too so it useleass`. That is big non sense as then you are doing something wrong in your apps code. But even then all filemanagers would display it (as all file managers will display hidden files wenn told).

The best to do is to put the files in a folder in internal memory. Then a filemanager can not see them. (At least when the phone is not rooted).

`thanking you in advanced to use your time...`. I hate such words.

Comment: see that " [add "." before folder name it will dispear pic my application too so it useleass.] " that i found that when you add "." as prefix in folder that mean android root not accept it and it not seen phone gallery but it also not seen in my app so this is useless feature for me and if you hat such words then better to ignore it..

Comment: Can you explain why an '.' before a folder name (a hidden folder) would be a problem for your app? There is no reason. And can you explain what this has to do with 'android root not accept it'? And you did not comment on my suggestion to use internal memory instead. Why?

Comment: see in my app i take pic/video in my activity which is store in sd card under my application name now my requirement is that user can't show app pic in device gallery / file manager under my app folder it should show a black folder at file manager, but when i use "." before my app folder name the image was also disappear from my application too. And  android root not accept in terms of it been not shown.

Comment: `when i use "." before my app folder name the image was also disappear from my application too`. I already twice told you that that is nonsense. Then you are doing something wrong. Explain please why your code has problems with a hidden folder. You should adapt your code.  `android root not accept in terms of it been not shown.`. Sorry i dont undestand a word of that. Please explain. I already asked you twice.

Comment: in my code i make a app folder in sd card and then use store my image under this folder and show my application using folder like "[ imageview.setImageURI(Uri.fromFile(file)); ]" when i use "." at that time i can't show image in my application.

Comment: You need only a few codelines for that. So please show those lines in a codeblock here. Put a working -well it should compile- (it does not work you said but this byside) example so we can copy/paste and try. And if you cannot show that image then exactly tell what is happening instead. And if there are errors or exceptions then name them all. Post the logcat if so.

Comment: for add just "." in folder name it totaly hide the image from everywhere (from gallery default app as well my app to ).

Answer (score 0):

@greenapps for add just "." in folder name it totaly hide the image from everywhere (from gallery default app as well my app to ).

but Thanks for spend  your thought i found my solution for hide the image from gallery app only

here i just call this function immediate after save a pic in my app folder,
this function delete the latest pic from the default **DCIM** folder but yes you have to validate that if the picture is taken or not cause ;-)

if you find anything wrong kindly notify me!

```
public void deleteImageFromGallery(String captureimageid) {

    Cursor c = null;
    Uri u = MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI;

    getContentResolver().delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=?",
            new String[]{captureimageid});

    String[] projection = {MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.SIZE, MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DISPLAY_NAME,
            MediaStore.Images.ImageColumns.DATA, BaseColumns._ID,};

    AppLog.i("InfoLog", "on activityresult Uri u " + u.toString());

    try {
        if (u != null) {
            c = managedQuery(u, projection, null, null, null);
        }
        if ((c != null) && (c.moveToLast())) {
            ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
            int i = cr.delete(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, BaseColumns._ID + "=" + c.getString(3),
                    null);
            AppLog.i("TAG", "Number of column deleted : " + i);
        }
    } finally {
        if (c != null) {
            c.close();
        }
    }
    sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.parse("file://"
            + Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory())));
}
```